# Where did original image go when using Paperclip to resize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using Paperclip and I have:

```
has_attached_file :img, :styles => { :thumb => "300x300>" }
```

The size of original image is `1024x768`. However, when I try access the image, only the thumb-styled image exists. How can I access the original image?

Comment: Do you not have any images in the `/original/` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
model.img.url(:original)
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation) for more information.

Comment: But there is only 1 file saved to amazon s3... and its not 1024x768

Comment: What you are saying is inconsistent with the Paperclip documentation and my experience in dealing with the gem. The only way one file would be present is if the original file was less than or equal to 300x300 since the `>` in your styles option will only generate the thumbnail if the original is greater than those dimensions. Could you try removing the `>` in your styles option to see if both files are uploaded to S3?

Comment: made no difference. I made some edits to make paperclip work on mongoid, but if it is shrinking the file, clearly paperclip's resize is working: https://github.com/hunterpp/paperclip

Comment: When I remove :styles => { :thumb => "300x300>" } then the original is uploaded....

Answer (score 0):

You can access the *original uploaded image* in `view` as below:

```
<%= image_tag @model.img.url %>
```

To access a *specific style* defined in `:styles` option of `has_attached_file`, you can use

```
<%= image_tag @model.img.url(:style_name) %>
```

which in your case can be

```
<%= image_tag @model.img.url(:thumb) %>
```

to display `:thumb` style of the uploaded image.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about aws file upload problem in the question. Please share the aws configuration details xxx out the access keys.